# tmux: How to get rid of "removed '/tmp/setup.sh.??????' when a new pane is created?

Tags: tmux

Since yesterday each time a new pane is created I get these two messages. How do I get rid of them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgKwd.png)

Comment: Is this strictly a tmux issue or does it happen in plain shell too?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have issues with your `.profile` of `bash`.  You can check that:

```
bash -l
exit
```

If this shows the problem, too, then it's definitively in the profile.  (If not, you need a different answer, sorry.)

In that case try

```
bash -x -l
exit
```

This dumps the whole startup process of `/bin/bash`.  To catch that, you can do

```
script
bash -x -l
exit
exit
```

The whole startup process then is in a file called `typescript`.  Use your favorite editor to search for the output to find the location, where the problem shows up.

Then the riddle starts to find, which file is the culprit, so which file has the `rm -vf`, probably of some `setup.sh` which was created with `mktemp`.

Have a look into the `FILES` section of `man bash`.  There are some files noted which are parsed.  All other files should be visible with following command:

```
fgrep '+ . ' typescript
```

FYI:

- The `.` is the `source` command of bash (see `help source` in `bash`).
- The above `fgrep` might miss some files which are included/invoked differently.

Final notes:

- This might only be a start, as the problem can hide quite deeper.  The first step is to be able to reproduce in a way that you can diagnose the problem.  This is the `bash -l`.  If this does not show the trouble, you need to look elsewhere.
- There might be some issue with your `$HOME/.tmux.conf` in how `bash` is invoked.  However I doubt this.  It it only happens in `tmux` it is more likely that something in your "profile"s reacts on `tmux`
- Welcome to SuperUser!

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right, it is not a tmux issue but a bash issue. However, I haven't found the exact problem yet, but I know where to look now.